# JavaFX: Null pointer Exception while trying in main fxml to access elements from another loaded fxml in to main fxml

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, fxmlloader

A main fxml is present.When clicked on center button center fxml file is loaded.
On clicking the button,the data in text field is accessed and set text label.the setText label is not working.It cannot be accessed.Null pointer exception is given.

**Test.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author root
 */
public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**main.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<BorderPane prefHeight="374.0" prefWidth="534.0" style="-fx-background-color: grey;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="test.mainController">
   <top>
      <HBox prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="tf" prefHeight="52.0" prefWidth="318.0" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="52.0" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </top>
   <center>
      <BorderPane fx:id="borderpane1" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <center>
            <HBox fx:id="hb" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" />
         </center>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </BorderPane>
   </center>
   <left>
      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#handleButtonAction1" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="99.0" text="Center" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </left>
</BorderPane>
```

**center.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="336.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="test.mainController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="label" prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="229.0" text="Label">
         <font>
            <Font size="56.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
   </padding>
</HBox>
```

**maincontroller.java**

```
package test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
public class mainController implements Initializable {

    public StringProperty nlt(){
        return  label.textProperty();
    }
    @FXML
    Label label;

    @FXML
    TextField tf;

    @FXML
    BorderPane borderpane1;

    @FXML 
     HBox hb;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(MouseEvent event)throws IOException {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        FXMLLoader Home;
        Home = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("center.fxml"));
        hb.getChildren();
        String s=tf.getText();
        System.out.println(s);
        label.setText(s);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction1(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader Home;
        Home = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("center.fxml"));
        //borderpane1.setCenter(Home);
        hb.getChildren().add((Node)Home.load());
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

Cannot change label.
Error=>Null Pointer EXception,java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.....

Comment: Please help.I tried a lot but can't find.

Comment: Each time you load an fxml file, you get a new controller. Just because you made them have the same class, you still have a different controller for the main FXML and the center fxml. Fields defined in center.fxml are only initialized in its controller, and fields defined in main.fxml are only initialized in its controller. You should 1. make the controllers different classes, so it is less confusing, and 2. [communicate between the controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14190310/2189127)